# How to get as much results as numbers inputted?

Tags: php

I have a password generator and with it you can choose the length of the password and which characters it should contain. However i want it to show as much passwords as numbers i put in the form at 'amount' and i can't make it seem to work. Does someone know the best way to do this?

The PHP

```
<?php

$small = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$big = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$num = "0123456789";
$char = ".-+=_,!@$#*%<>[]{}";
$chars = "";
$val = $_POST['length'];

function generatePassword($length, $chars){
    $charsArray = str_split($chars);
    $password = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        shuffle($charsArray);
        $password .= $charsArray[0];
    }

    echo "Wachtwoord:<br><br><textarea cols='50' rows='10' disabled>$password</textarea><br><br>";


}

if(isset($_POST['generate'])){

    if(isset($_POST['char'])){
        $chars .= $char;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['num'])){
        $chars .= $num;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['small'])){
        $chars .= $small;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['big'])){
        $chars .= $big;
    }

    generatePassword(htmlspecialchars($_POST['length']), $chars);

}


?>
```

And the HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Aantal:</label>
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="<?=$_POST['amount']?>" required>
    <br><br>
    <label>Lengte:</label>
    <input type="number" name="length" value="<?=$_POST['length']?>" required>
    <br><br>
    <label>Karakters</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="char">(@#$%)
    <br><br>
    <label>Getallen:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="num">(123456)
    <br><br>
    <label>Kleine letters:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="small">(abcdefg)
    <br><br>
    <label>Hoofdletters:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="big">(ABCDEFG)
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Genereer wachtwoord" name="generate">
</form>
```

Comment: Well the first thing to do is collect the number from `$_POST['amount']` and write a loop to loop for `amount` times

Comment: Pro tip: Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a loop with `amount`?

```html
<?php

$small = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$big = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$num = "0123456789";
$char = ".-+=_,!@$#*%<>[]{}";
$chars = "";
$val = $_POST['length'];

function generatePassword($length, $chars){
    $charsArray = str_split($chars);
    $password = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        shuffle($charsArray);
        $password .= $charsArray[0];
    }

    echo "Wachtwoord:<br><br><textarea cols='50' rows='10' disabled>$password</textarea><br><br>";


}

if(isset($_POST['generate'])){

    if(isset($_POST['char'])){
        $chars .= $char;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['num'])){
        $chars .= $num;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['small'])){
        $chars .= $small;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['big'])){
        $chars .= $big;
    }

    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        generatePassword(htmlspecialchars($_POST['length']), $chars);
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: I had not tried it yet but it works now, Thank you very much :)